# I have made a dockerfile and I was going to run it on AWS ECS but I cant as it requires -t

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ec2

Here is my docker run and the docker file is there a reason why it requires -t and isnt working on ECS thanks for any help. I dont 
understand what -t does so if someone could also help with that thanks.

This is just a basic docker that connects to my rds and uses wordpress. I dont have any plugins and shapely is the theme i'm using .

```
command docker run -t --name wordpress -d -p 80:80 dockcore/wordpress 



FROM ubuntu

#pt-get clean all
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install unzip wget mysql-client mysql-server apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 pwgen python-setuptools vim-tiny php7.0-mysql  php7.0-lda
RUN rm -fr /var/cashe/*files neeeded
ADD wordpress.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Wordpress install
RUN wget -P /var/www/html/ https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
RUN unzip /var/www/html/latest.zip -d /var/www/html/
RUN rm -fr /var/www/html/latest.zip

# Copy he wp config file
RUN cp /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php

# Expose web port
EXPOSE 80

# wp config for database
RUN sed -ie 's/database_name_here/wordpress/g' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
RUN sed -ie 's/username_here/root/g' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
RUN sed -ie 's/password_here/password/g' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
RUN sed -ie 's/localhost/wordpressrds.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/g' /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
RUN rm -fr /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/*
RUN rm -fr /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/*
ADD /shapely /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/

# Start apache on boot
RUN echo "service apache2 start" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: So has this image been built container? At what stage are you getting the error and what is the exact error?

Comment: I can build and then run it with command docker run -t --name wordpress -d -p 80:80 dockcore/wordpress but when I use command docker run --name wordpress -d -p 80:80 dockcore/wordpress it just doesn't seem to run. I don't think ECS supports tty and it spits out its generic error "essential conrainer in task exited ".

Comment: Try -it instead of -t

Comment: It works with -it but firstly why is it needed and I don't think it is supported with AWS ECS but I might be wrong and have a different error.

Comment: There could be some environmental variables in your local system that means that running docker run always assumes -t. I personally always run containers with -it if I want an interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple problems. First of all your container should never require `-t` in order to run unless it is a temporary container that you plan to interact with using a shell. Background containers shouldn't require an interactive TTY interface, they just run in the background autonomously.

Second in your docker file I see a lot of `RUN` statements which are basically the build time commands for setting up the initial state of the container, but you don't have any `CMD` statement.

You need a `CMD` which is the process to actually kick off and start in the container when you try to run the container. `RUN` statements only execute once during the initial docker build, and then the results of those run statements are saved into the container image. When you run a docker container it has the initial state that was setup by the `RUN` statements, and then the `CMD` statement kicks off a running process in the container.

So it looks like that last `RUN` in your Dockerfile should be a `CMD` since the Apache server is the long running process that you want to run with the container state that you previously setup using all those `RUN` statements.

Another thing you should do is chain many of those consecutive `RUN` statements into one. Docker creates a separate layer for each `RUN` command, where each layer is kind of like a Git commit of the state of the container. So it is very wasteful to have so many `RUN` statements because it makes way too many container layers. You can do something like this ot chain RUN statements together instead to make a smaller, more efficient container:

```
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install unzip wget mysql-client mysql-server apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 pwgen python-setuptools vim-tiny php7.0-mysql  php7.0-lda && \
    rm -fr /var/cashe/*files neeeded
```

I recommend reading through this guide from Docker that covers best practices for writing a Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd

Comment: Thanks for that but I did use the && \ but I changed it because I was getting and error but it didn't fix it.